# Powershell script to move files from one folder to another

Tags: powershell

Txt Files are in root folder Working folder. Files will be moving ones permonth to Archive folder which is listed in Working folder.
This is the script I am using to move files to Archive folder.

```
$source = "N:\Working Folder"
$dest = "N:\Working Folder\Archive" 

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $newPath = $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source),$dest
    Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
}
```

Getting the error

```
Move-Item : Cannot find path 'N:\Working Folder\Archive' because it does not exist.
At N:\Script\Script.ps1:10 char:5
+     Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (N:\Script\Archive:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotF
```

But these are the path. I have also tried with \servername\n$\folder but same error

```
$source = "N:\Working Folder"
$dest = "N:\Working Folder\Archive" 

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $newPath = $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source),$dest
    Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
}
```

Getting the error

```
Move-Item : Cannot find path 'N:\Working Folder\Archive' because it does not exist.
At N:\Script\Script.ps1:10 char:5
+     Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (N:\Script\Archive:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotF
```

But these are the path. I have also tried with \servername\n$\folder but same error

Comment: You could simply use `Move-Item $source\* -Destination $dest` I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem related to the destination path not existing, check that the `Archive` folder exists within the `Working Folder` directory. If it doesn't exist, you can create it using the following PowerShell command:

```
$source = "N:\Working Folder"
$dest = "N:\Working Folder\Archive" 

# Create the Archive folder if it doesn't exist
if (-not (Test-Path $dest)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $dest
}

Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.Name} -Force
```

Comment: Why would `[regex]::Escape()` be needed? Why not `Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dest -Force`?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion that would indeed be a simpler approach!

Comment: I am not sure `Join-Path` is needed. If the `-Destination` is a container (directory), then the same `Name` will be used. Is there something I am missing about the need for `[regex]::Escape()`?

Comment: Thank you XM01, code works like a charm with no issues. I have to now add code so that it moves to a different folder monthly.